# Is there a way to access the underlying bluetooth settings in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm not sure how to ask this question so as not to get yelled at, but my DroidX's bluetooth media output is too low and I'm wondering if I can write an app that allows me to boost max decible level at the hardware level  (since moving the slider to max doesn't do it).  I don't see access to the underlying hardware settings anywhere, but am hoping that's a carrier level restriction and that Android does have access to those lower level settings.

I have verified that my headphones are not the issue, as other devices produce a significantly higher volume.  Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staring at the BlueZ source (see line 953 of https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/+/master/audio/headset.c
) the headset layer does appear to have a gain setting. With an appropriate amount of digging and some serious elbow grease I should imagine you might be able to modify this from native code. Not sure if it would work for A2DP headsets, and how it interacts with the Android audio subsystem, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Well, the source is in git, so you can get it: actually writing BlueZ compatible interface code to override the gain on Android and getting that to compile using the NDK and then calling that from an app? If you figure that one out please write an article.